# IdentityServer 4 with Active Directory on Premise

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

Our client have many applications and they want to integrate it to just log once (single sign on), but they want that using active directory on premise they have their own server.

We decided to evaluate identityserver so we found this http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html that identitserver 4 support active directory but here we dont see where we are going to put the LPAD//... route to connect to the active directory... so we are with doubts if identityserver supports or not Active directory or Maybe we cant undertand it very well. Thank you.

Comment: link to documentation is broken

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IdentityServer supports multiple ways to authenticate Windows users

- Windows integrated authentication if the machine running IS is domain joined (as the documentation describes)
- Username/password login page via LDAP (manual code from the account controller)
- via federation (e.g. with OpenID Connect/ADFS or a domain joined IdentityServer)

Comment: Is it some samle with second way - as you mentioned - via LDAP? I think that sample will be great and it something that missing there because it is very typical scenario. I have tried find similiar issue but without any success.

Comment: @leastprivilege - I'm struggling to find any documentation, guides, etc. regarding the approach you mentioned in your second point.


> Username/password login page via LDAP (manual code from the account controller)

Comment: https://github.com/Nordes/IdentityServer4.LdapExtension/blob/master/README.md This may help for the second one.

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-active-directory-ad-as-the-repository-for-authentication-with-identityserver4-fa010e0980db